Multi-agent supervisor langgrpah giving json related error
I was making a supervised agent using langgraph with two agents (rag and sql) using the template from langchain below
Official Doc one : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KEe9YSTGDQopMuss3CSMHJ3VjDzzrGSh?usp=sharing
My code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QszbxpiFJkhWWYhBpSmDCX_3MMMeHVdd?usp=sharing
however when i run my code (link above) at the end i get the error below which seems routeresponse should generate in json and it doesnt. Any idea how i can fix this will be very much appreciated:
OutputParserException: Function RouteResponse arguments:

{
next: "Rag_agent"
}

are not valid JSON. Received JSONDecodeError Expecting property name 
enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 5 (char 6)

